# How do I stop prism.js from processing automatically

Tags: prism.js

I want to call Prism.highlightElement or Prism.highlightAll after doing some other javascript processing on my code blocks. I can somewhat control the moment that Prism processes by where I place the `<script src="prism.js"></script>` but I don't see a way to disable automated processing.

Answer (score 0):

Super kludgy answer:

Even though I asked for the development, not minified, version of prism.js when I download, what I got is kind of minified. Anyway, I found this bit of code:

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")
```

and changed it to this:

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("scriptxx")
```

So, nothing gets highlighted now, until I explicitly call `Prism.highlightAll()`.